# How to enable qt5 pushbuttons in python at the end of a certain process

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, qt5

I am using python 3.6. There's a process calling a long time task. After the task is completed I want to enable some widgets, but it doesn't work because I am calling the function in the process.

```
def func1(self):
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.func2)
    proc.start()
def func2(self):
    #Long time work is here
    self.func3()
def func3(self):
    self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(True)
    self.pushButton_3.setEnabled(True)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it's solved by using multiprocessing manager dictionary with event listener